# Let $U,W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be subspaces. Assume that $U \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $U^\perp \oplus W^\perp=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I started by writing out the definitions of $U^\perp$ and $W^\perp$ as
$$U^\perp=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\langle x,u \rangle =0, \forall u\in U\} \qquad W^\perp=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n:\langle y,w \rangle =0, \forall w \in W\}$$
Sadly I dont really know how to progress from this point (if you can even call this a start). I thought about writing any vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $r$ and then letting $r = u \oplus w$. However, I do not see how this helps.

Any tips?

Comment: I just came up with this, but I feel like its not correct. We know that $\mathbb{R^n}=U^\perp \oplus U$ and $\mathbb{R^n}=W \oplus U$. Thus $U^\perp \oplus U = W \oplus U \implies W = U^\perp$. Doing the same for $W^\perp$ will allow you to obtain $W^\perp = U$. Then its just a simple equality.  But I'm positive this cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to prove that $W^{\bot} \cap U^{\bot} = \{0\}$ and then you use some dimension argument like $$\dim U+\dim U^{\bot }=n$$
for every subspace $U$.

---

Let $w_1,w_2,...,w_k$ be a basis for $W$ and let $u_1,u_2,...,u_m$ be a basis for $U$. Then all these vector form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ so $k+m=n$, since $U \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^n$.

If $v\in W^{\bot} \cap U^{\bot}$ then $v\cdot w_i=0$ and $v\cdot u_j=0$ for all $i,j$. So $v$ is in $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\bot} = \{0\}$ so $v=0$.

Since $W^{\bot} \oplus U^{\bot} \leq \mathbb{R}^n$ we have  $$n=(n- k)+(n-m)= \dim W^{\bot} +  \dim U^{\bot} =\dim (W^{\bot} \oplus U^{\bot})\leq n$$

So $\dim (W^{\bot} \oplus U^{\bot}) = n$ so $W^{\bot} \oplus U^{\bot} = \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: How do you know that $\dim{(W^\perp \oplus U^\perp)} = \dim{W^\perp} + \dim{U^\perp}$?

Comment: First sentence...........

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was how can we create a dimension argument like that?